# How can I separate distinct exams into individual pdf files? (exam class)

Tags: exam

In compiling a series of exams (between ~10 and ~20 different tests, each with four questions), I would hope to have a single document, and a single preamble, using the `exam` class, but each individual exam printed to a different output file, for ease of distribution.

I noted the question [Variations of an exam](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57012/variations-of-an-exam) where similar (but not identical) exam questions are addressed to different "groups" of people facing a particular version of the exam, where only a part of the question changes between the different groups, as well as [Making exams with multiple-choice questions in scrambled versions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/360518/making-exams-with-multiple-choice-questions-in-scrambled-versions)
but they don't focus on separation to different output files.

As a separate resource, I could call on a script to act on the .pdf of the entire set of exams, and using `qpdf` separate the file in N files, one per group. But this needs manual specification of which pages belong to which group.
Not ideal.
Perhaps this can be handled by an entirely separate package?

Comment: Are these exams administered electronically? Otherwise you can (physically) print the whole pdf and give every student only the relevant pages of that printout.

Comment: yes, I should ideally send the files to each student electronically. And they should only have their own exam, not that of the others. Otherwise I could have given them the whole pdf and ask to focus solely on their part.

Comment: PDFs can be split into single pages or whatever gathering of pages with external apps like ilovepdf.com.

Comment: each latex run can only make one pdf but you can easily have conditionals in the document so make different output sets on different runs